# Show NSWindow from separate nib (not modal)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nswindow, nsapplication

How to do it? I simply want to load a window and show it in front of the main window.

```
NSWindowController* controller = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"MyWindow"];
NSWindow* myWindow = [controller window];
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
```

This code shows the window for one moment and then hides it. IMHO this is because I don't keep reference to the window (I use `ARC`). `[NSApp runModalForWindow: myWindow];` works perfectly but I don't need to show it modally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with ARC if you don't hold a reference to the window it will be torn down as soon you as you exit the routine you were in. You need to hold a strong reference to it in an ivar. `[NSApp runModalForWindow: myWindow]` is different because the `NSApplication` object holds a reference to the window as long as it is being run modally.

Answer (score 1):

You should likely do something similar to the following, which creates a `strong` reference to the `NSWindowController` instance you create:

.h:

```
@class MDWindowController;
@interface MDAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    __weak IBOutlet NSWindow        *window;
    MDWindowController              *windowController;
}
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) MDWindowController *windowController;

- (IBAction)showSecondWindow:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m:

```
#import "MDAppDelegate.h"
#import "MDWindowController.h"

@implementation MDAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize windowController;

- (IBAction)showSecondWindow:(id)sender {
    if (windowController == nil) windowController =
                        [[MDWindowController alloc] init];
    [windowController showWindow:nil];
}

@end
```

Note that rather than sending the `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` method directly to the `NSWindowController`'s `NSWindow`, you can just use `NSWindowController`'s built-in `showWindow:` method.

While the above code (and sample project below) use a custom subclass of `NSWindowController`, you also use a generic `NSWindowController` and create the instance using `initWithWindowNibName:` (just make sure the File's Owner of the nib file is set to `NSWindowController` rather than a custom subclass like `MDWindowController`).

Sample project:

http://www.markdouma.com/developer/MDWindowController.zip